# Need to sum numbers when a value in a different column appears

Tags: sql

I want to sum values in a column but they are repeated and each entry is linked to a different view. The table looks something like this -

| id | User Count | View |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | Reporting |
| 2 | 500 | Accounting |
| 3 | 500 | Marketing |
| 4 | 500 | Reporting |

How would I go about only summing up user count only for Reporting view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(UserCount) from Table where View='Reporting';
```

Answer (score 0):

select View, sum(UserCount) as TotalUser from Table group by
View

HAVING View='Reporting'; -- you can comment this clause to see sum for all View